# Дополнить функцию для удаления строк

Tags: python-3.x

```
УДК 625.01
РЕФЕРАТ

Дипломный проект содержит: 138 страниц, рисунков – 6, таблиц – 5, чертежей – 8.
Наиболее часто встречающиеся слова и выражения:
ВОДОПРОПУСКНАЯ ТРУБА, ЖЕЛЕЗОБЕТОННАЯ ТРУБА, УДЛИНЕНИЕ ТРУБЫ, КАПИТАЛЬНЫЙ РЕМОНТ ЖЕЛЕЗНОДОРОЖНОГО ПУТИ, ЭЛЕКТРОБЕЗОПАСНОСТЬ, МОНТЕР ПУТИ.
Объектом исследования является участок  Горьковской железной дороги.
В дипломном проекте поставлена цель – разработать проект производства работ по капитальному ремонту железнодорожного пути двумя вариантами. Выполнена  технико-экономическое сравнение вариантов  строительства.
В процессе работы проведен анализ водопропускных трубы, а так же их реконструкции. Рассмотрен раздел электробезопасность.
```

Из данного текста необходимо получить количество страниц. Я это осуществила так:

```
from docx import Document
document_a = Document("Реферат.docx")
for para in document_a.paragraphs:
    a = para.text
    #print(a)
    if 'страниц' in a:
        bf = re.findall(r'\d+', a)
        print('#215: ^A' + bf[0] + '^Ca-рис.^0a-табл.')
        print('#920: PAZK')
        print('#900: ^Tl^B05^Cj13^Xk')
```

Но теперь мне нужно удалить весь текст до слов, напечатанных в верхнем регистре. И удалить нужно так, чтобы не осталось пробелов:

```
def get_clear():
    if 'УДК: 625.1' in a:
        return ''
    elif 'РЕФЕРАТ' in a:
        return ''
    else:
        return a
```

К сожалению, после моей функции пробелы всё равно остаются. Подскажите, пожалуйста, более эффективное решение. Заранее благодарна

Comment: Текст у вас построчно обрабатывается, или весь текст в одной строке? Куда потом записывается после обработки?

Comment: @insolor, текст разбит на параграфы. Насколько я понимаю, его можно обработать построчно. Записывается в формулу по полям. Например формула для страниц: `'#215: ^A' + bf[0] + '^Ca-рис.^0a-табл.'`

Comment: "Разбит на параграфы" - это "логическое" форматирование текста. Я уточняю, в каком виде он у вас в программе хранится: в виде списка строк, или просто из текстового файла построчно читаете, или это одна сплошная строка или еще какой-то вариант? Наверное проще будет, если вы добавите в вопрос код, который у вас уже есть.

Comment: @insolor, добавила код в вопрос

Comment: Тут скорее всего не через функцию нужно будет делать, а просто проверять, что в строке нет "УДК" или "РЕФЕРАТ", и тогда выводить `a` (если есть эти строки, то просто ничего не делать). Вообще зависит от того, как в значение из `get_clear` потом планируете использовать.

Comment: @insolor, в идеале мне нужно весь текст после строки в верхнем регистре запихнуть в поле 331. И я сейчас ищу варианты как это сделать.

Comment: @Ireen1985, у вас преложение в верхнем регистре всегда после текста: `"Наиболее часто встречающиеся слова и выражения:"` идёт?

Comment: @MaxU, к сожалению, нет. Все файлы очень разные. Их объединяет одно - посредине идет предложение в верхнем регистре